# Using Curl to POST data

Tags: curl

I am having trouble understanding how to POST data using Curl if someone could please walk me through how to POST the data listed below I might be able to understand it better

```
POST /play HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: iTunes/10.6 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.3) AppleWebKit/535.18.5
Content-Length: 163
Content-Type: text/parameters

Content-Location: http://192.168.1.18:3689/airplay.mp4
Start-Position: 0.174051
```

If I Telnet using Putty on windows and post exactly what is listed above it works but I have been reading that Curl is used to basically do the same thing and after much reading my brain hurts. I hope this is enough information to get help if not just let me know and I can try to provide more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the curl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

- Use [`--user-agent`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-A) to send a different user-Agent header
- Use [`--header`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) to add the Content-Type header (Content-Length is calculated automatically)
- `--header Accept:` suppresess the accept header that curl sends by default
- [`--data-binary`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) can be used to set the request body. This implies POST.
- Finally, add the URL you want to post to.

All in all, it should look like:

```
curl -A 'iTunes/10.6 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.3) AppleWebKit/535.18.5' \
     --header 'Content-Type: text/parameters' \
     --header 'Accept:' \
     --data-binary $(/bin/echo -e \
'Content-Location: http://192.168.1.18:3689/airplay.mp4\r\nStart-Position: 0') \
     http://example.example/play
```

Comment: I tried your method with no errors but it is not working as intended. Is this doing the same thing as it would be by pasting it in Telnet?

Comment: I am not familiar with using WireShark or what to look for in the packets I have captured the sessions and named them accordingly. I have shared them in this link if you would like to take a look at them feel free. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yu3kzkc67r18fic/5XNz6OH486

Comment: Thank your very much for the dump, that allows efficient debugging. As far as I can see, the only remaining differences are the additional accept header (see updated version of the answer) and the fractional `Start-Position` in the data. Can you retry with `Start-Position: 0` and the updated curl code?

Comment: Still does not work as intended I have captured this session as well and it looks identical to the previous one. I have added it to the dropbox folder if you feel like taking a look at it again. The only thing I noticed differently between the working telnet session and the non working curl session is that it shows several more `[TCP segement of a reassembled PDU]` and in each one there is one line for example `POST /play HTTP/1.1` is inside its own and then there is another packet with nothing after the packet with nothing would be the `User-agent` string not sure if this matters or not

Comment: By the way thanks for the continued help I greatly appreciate it

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed one other thing: The newline is actually a Windows-style newline (`\r\n`) in the telnet version, but a UNIX-style newline (`\n`) in the curl one. The segment duplicates, and whether lines are sent in packets of their own do not matter for TCP, where the receiver OS buffers that out anyways.